# popoverviewController crash on iPhone, works on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller

a noob question here:

any ideas why this code:

```
UIViewController* popoverviewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

[webViewnetwork loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"webView" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
[popoverView addSubview:webViewnetwork];

popoverviewController.view = popoverView;
popoverviewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake (100, 100);

self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverviewController];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

would work fine on iPad, but crash on iPhone ?
I'm trying to do the same thing as in my iPad version, which is adding a subview with an html formatted text. It crashes (program received signal: SIGABRT) on the 7th line (initWithContentViewController)

thank you!

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html 
says "Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `UIPopoverController` is only available on the iPad.

Comment: lol. that would explain. thank you. what's the closest equivalent that I could/should use ? something simple to display an html formatted info text (around 25 lines of text) with a dismiss button or a similar technique

Comment: Presenting a modal view controller is probably the closest equivalent to displaying a popover.

Comment: excellent, thank you. works great now with the modal view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a UIPopoverController with iPhone.  U will need to detect which device idiom u are using and present the appropriate viewController type at runtime.

The project [here](https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/BDApplicationHelpers) provides some examples.  The basic gist of it is the following:

```
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
     /* use iPhone related viewController via either presentModal or via UIViewController containment */
 }else{
     /* Using an iPad use a popoverController */
 }
```

Good Luck.

Comment: thanks. I have two separate iPhone and iPad versions so I'll just implement something else for the iPhone