# UIPrintInteractionController inside popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I've to implement `UIPrintInteractionController` inside popup. I've implemented -

```
(UIViewController *)printInteractionControllerParentViewController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController {
    UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:address.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [popover.contentViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    navigationController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 540);
    return navigationController;
}
```

But it crashes saying :

```
reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'
```

Even on testing in ipad simulator. what to do ? I've to implement popup just like [image: this].

Comment: your issue is about diff size screens

Comment: @vaibhav what should i do if i'm targetting ipads.

Comment: see my ans if it is helpful ..

Answer (score 0):

you can figure out the difference device whether it is iPad or iPhone using below code ..

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // code for iPad here 
}else{

    // code for iPhone here
}
```

> updated

- you can use custom view to popover using below method by passing a uiview to it.

  ```
  -(void) popOver:(UIView *)view{

  view.hidden = NO;

  view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);   // view to popup
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                   animations:^{
                       view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
               } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   [UIView  animateWithDuration:0.1
                                     animations:^{
                                         view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9,0.9); // custom view
                                     }completion:^(BOOL  finished) {
                                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
                                             view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;   // custom view to pop
                                         }];
                                     }];
               }];

  }
  ```

> this method shows a uiview like popover now will be able to add any of the UI components over it.

Comment: i've seen this answer and i've implemented this but it is not helpful. I want to know how can do this for Ipad?

Comment: the above code is just perfect to classify iPad or iPhone ..please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: possibly this will be the ans of your problem till i understand ..have alook of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391176/popoverviewcontroller-crash-on-iphone-works-on-ipad).

Comment: but i'm using ipad simulator, shouldn't that should go inside if and not else.

Comment: but why doesn't that go inside if condition, even on real ipad and not simulator?